# How to convert Points(pt) to Pixels(px) for all Screen sizes

Tags: android, prototyping, zeplin

I am using Zeplin https://zeplin.io/ Software for Prototyping , When i Export Sketch File to it , it shows size values in Points pt .
 Let's suppose i made screens with resolution 1080*1920 , so values should exactly match when i use these values in android XML . but it doesn't . So i am wondering is there a problem in that software or My formula for conversion of pt to PX is wrong , i.e 1 pt=1.333 PX

Comment: Point are mostly used in the iOS development. Take a look at this answer that makes a comparison between different units in Android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp. Also, keep in mind that in Android it's a really edge case to have views with a given size because most of them have the size big enough to fit their content.

Comment: do these software change resolution of sketch screens? or they keep them with same resolution at the of export?